# Size of UITableViewCell has major impact on smooth scrolling?

Tags: ipad, uitableview

G'day guys,

I'm building an iPad app at the moment and our designer has given us a view that has an image background and a tableview that covers a section of that background (it isn't transparent don't worry about that). Each cell contains information about stores. I've implemented it by looking at the smoothscrolling code from Loren Brichter and modifying it a bit for my purposes, but I'm having an issue where the app is just hanging when I try to scroll really fast (hanging in the simulator, I've yet to install it onto the iPad but I've not seen much of a difference in performance between the pad and the simulator)

I've nuked all calls to any data structures and just have the cell information statically generated, so I could test to see if they were what was causing problems and they don't seem to be.

The cell measures: 620px wide by 300px high.

Is that far too large to have the tableview manage them? Would we have to figure out another way to implement it or is there something I've simply missed (or is the simulator simply a bit buggered?)

When I fire up instruments to check when I'm testing it it's either stuck in: mach_msg_trap or CA::Render.

Any ideas on how to speed it up/make it even better?

Cheers

Comment: are the cells just text or are there images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out this was entirely based on issues with the simulator and not issues with the iPad itself.

Obviously the increased complexity of a cell causes issues in rendering, but if you are using Quartz to draw the cells you get a substantially reduced overhead.